# mysql particular query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table: `teams` and `formations`:

Table **teams**:

```
team_id | team_name
   1    | Barcelona
   2    | Real Madrid
   3    | PSG
```

Table **formations**:

```
formation_id | team_id | module
    1        |    2    | 5-3-2
    2        |    1    | 4-4-2
    3        |    3    | 4-4-2
    4        |    2    | 4-4-3
```

Pratically i have need of "join" between the 2 table GROUP BY team_id but with the last "formation_id"

The result my be this:

```
 team_id | team_name  | formation_id  | module
    1    | Barcelona  |     2         |  4-4-2
    2    | Real Madrid|     4         |  4-4-3
    3    | PSG        |     3         |  4-4-2
```

Actually my query is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM formations f
 INNER JOIN teams t 
    ON (f.team_id = t.team_id)
 GROUP BY t.team_id
```

With my query I selected the first insert formation for each team, instead I must select the last formations for each team.

Comment: when you say "last" do you mean "largest" ?

Comment: not largest, last formation_id for each team_id

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
SELECT t.team_id,
       t.team_name,
       f.formation_id,
       f.module
  FROM teams t
  JOIN formations f
    ON f.team_id = t.team_id
       -- require f.formation_id to be MAX(formation_id) for some team:
  JOIN ( SELECT MAX(formation_id) AS id
           FROM formations
          GROUP
             BY team_id
       ) max_formation_ids
    ON max_formation_ids.id = f.formation_id
;
```

or:

```
SELECT t.team_id,
       t.team_name,
       f.formation_id,
       f.module
  FROM teams t
  JOIN formations f
    ON f.team_id = t.team_id
       -- require f.formation_id to be MAX(formation_id) for this team:
 WHERE f.formation_id =
        ( SELECT MAX(formation_id)
            FROM formations
           WHERE team_id = t.team_id
        )
;
```

or:

```
SELECT t.team_id,
       t.team_name,
       f.formation_id,
       f.module
  FROM teams t
  JOIN formations f
    ON f.team_id = t.team_id
       -- forbid f.formation_id to be less than another for the same team:
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN formations f2
    ON f2.team_id = t.team_id
   AND f2.formation_id > f.formation_id
 WHERE f2.formation_id IS NULL
;
```

Comment: This will work only if `formation_id` is unique or the primary key.

Comment: If the primary key is `(team_id, formation_id)`, it will fail.

Comment: The subquery is doing more work than it needs to, since it is internally producing the highest formation_id for all teams, not just the team in the current row.

Comment: @ypercube: The question seems to imply that `formation_id` is indeed the primary key, so I've made that assumption. Do you disagree with it?

Comment: @FredSobotka: It's an uncorrelated subquery, so there *is* no "current row". The OP's query pulls all teams, so the subquery is actually doing *exactly* the work that it needs to!

Comment: The amount of unnecessary expense in that subquery depends on whether the optimizer is smart enough to execute the subquery just once and reuse its contents for all rows that are produced by the join, or if it decides to discard and re-execute the subquery for every row of the join. My experience has been that even uncorrelated subqueries that are referenced in the WHERE clause, such as the one in this answer, are typically discarded and recomputed for each qualifying row. If that is also the case here, then a correlated subquery bound to t.team_id would produce the same result more cheaply.

Comment: @FredSobotka: As long as the OP is using a recent version of MySQL, it should be fine: the optimizer will convert it to a semi-join.

Comment: @ruakh: I'm not sure that (even MySQL 5.5) will have such a smart behaviour. I think only MariaDB (5.3 and 5.5) optimizer is good enough to calculate the subquery one once. (and possibly MySQL 5.6 but that is still beta)

Comment: And I've +1 your answer as it returns the wanted results.

Comment: @FredSobotka: Hmm, never mind; I've just read through [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/semi-joins.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/semi-joins.html), and it turns out that even the very recentest versions of MySQL are fairly incompetent at using hash-joins for `IN`-style semi-joins. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks for the +1, and thanks for the nudge! See my immediately-preceding comment to FredSobotka.

Comment: Check this too: [MariaDB 5.3 Optimizer: Feature Comparison Matrix](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/what-is-mariadb-53/#feature-comparison-matrix) @FredSobotka: cc

Answer (score 1):

**Check this [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aa9f/7)**

```
SELECT A.team_id,A.team_name,B.formation_id,B.module
FROM teams A,formations B
WHERE A.team_id=B.team_id
AND B.formation_id =
(
  SELECT max(formation_id)
  FROM formations C
  WHERE C.team_id =B.team_id
 )
ORDER BY A.team_id;


create table teams
(  
  team_id int
 ,team_name varchar(40)
);
create table formations 
(
  formation_id int
 ,team_id  int
 ,module int
);
insert into teams
values
(1,'Barcelona'),(2,'Real Madrid'),(3,'PSG');
insert into formations
values
(1,2,532),(2,1,442),(3,3,442),(4,2,443);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find their maximum formation ID using a subquery that you will later join it with the original tables. Try this one,

```
SELECT  a.*, c.formation_ID, c.`module`
FROM    teams a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT team_id, MAX(formation_ID) maxID
            FROM formations
            GROUP BY team_ID
        ) b ON  a.team_id = b.team_id
        INNER JOIN formations c
            ON  c.team_id = b.team_id AND
                c.formation_ID = b.maxID
ORDER BY a.Team_id
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/079fb/2)

Answer (score 0):

SQL spec states that when you use group by clause then all fields/expressions in the output should be either results of aggregate functions (like count, avg, etc) or fields listed in group by clause. otherwise the behavior is not defined. So if you need to pick exactly this record you need to add some criteria to your query. Also, there is no guarantee that simple 'select * from some_table' would always return rows in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
select f.*, t.team_name from formations f
  join (select team_id, max(formation_id) as max_formation_id from formations f 
          group by team_id) as mrf on mrf.max_formation_id = f.formation_id
  join teams t on f.team_id = t.team_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table teams (team_id integer, team_name varchar(50));
create table formations (formation_id integer, team_id integer, module varchar(20));

insert into formations (formation_id, team_id, module) values
(1, 2, '5-3-2'),
(2, 1, '4-4-2'),
(3, 3, '4-4-2'),
(4, 2, '4-4-3')
;

insert into teams (team_id, team_name) values
(1, 'Barcelona'),
(2, 'Real Madrid'),
(3, 'PSG')
;

select t.team_id, team_name, f.formation_id, module
from
    formations f
    inner join
    teams t on f.team_id = t.team_id
    inner join (
        select team_id, max(formation_id) as formation_id
        from formations
        group by team_id
    ) s on s.team_id = t.team_id and s.formation_id = f.formation_id
order by t.team_id
;
+---------+-------------+--------------+--------+
| team_id | team_name   | formation_id | module |
+---------+-------------+--------------+--------+
|       1 | Barcelona   |            2 | 4-4-2  |
|       2 | Real Madrid |            4 | 4-4-3  |
|       3 | PSG         |            3 | 4-4-2  |
+---------+-------------+--------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This version produces the same result without aggregates, which often incur internal sorting.

```
SELECT t.team_id,
   t.team_name,
   f.formation_id,
   f.module
FROM teams t
INNER JOIN formations f
    ON f.team_id = t.team_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN formations f2
    ON f2.team_id = t.team_id
   AND f2.formation_id > f.formation_id
WHERE f2.formation_id IS NULL
```